# How to put specific data for each fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have four fragments that are created programmatically and I send some data as list into those fragments using the new instance approach.

```
public static FragmentMasaDesign newInstance(ArrayList<String> myList, String myString) {
    FragmentMasaDesign myFragment = new FragmentMasaDesign();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArrayList("myList", myList);
    args.putString("myString", myString);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);
    return myFragment;
}
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.list = getArguments().getStringArrayList("myList");
    this.string= getArguments().getString("myString");
 }
```

There is no problem when I switch fragments in a sequence. However when I swap the fragment 1 to 4 it creates the fourth fragment then it creates the third one. The current fragment on the screen is fourth fragment but when I check the `myList` and `myString` they refer to the list that I sent to the fragment 3. How can I specify arguments for each fragment or how can I force `FragmentPagerAdapter` to create one fragment?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `newInstance` approach you can directly set the variable, you don't need to call `setArguments()` and `getArguments()`

```
public static FragmentMasaDesign newInstance(ArrayList<String> myList, String myString) {
    FragmentMasaDesign myFragment = new FragmentMasaDesign();
    myFragment.list = list;
    myFragment.string = myString;
    return myFragment;
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}
```